# how can I hide "read more" on teaser

Tags: php, module, drupal-7, view

I created a view displaying some teasers that link to my galleries on http://quaaoutlodge.com/gallery. You note the "read more" links on top of the images, I'd like to get rid of them but am unsure how. Any help or assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Ron

**EDIT:**

The teaser implementation in my node.tpl.php looks like this:

```
<?php if (!$teaser): ?>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I ended up leaving my node.tpl.php untouched and returned it to its original state but to resolve my problem, i just gave my image style a z-index i.e. I changed

```
.node-gallery img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

to

```
.node-gallery img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This works beatifully for me. I'm sure its not the solution for everyone but what this told me, sometimes the solution isn't as far away or as complicated as one might think in the beginning...! :)

Answer (score 1):

In `node.css` at path

> `http://quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/themes/marinelli/css/node.css`

search for `span.teaser-readmore` and and add `display: none;` like below

```
.teaser-meta span.teaser-readmore{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-left: 23px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Can you try this in `node.tpl.php`

```
<?php 
if($teaser){
      print l(t('Read more'), 'node/' . $nid, array('attributes' => array('class' => t('node-readmore-link')))); 
  } 
?>
should be

<?php
if($teaser)
  print 
    l(
       t('Read more<span class="element-invisible"> about @title</span>'),
       'node/' . $nid,
        array(
             'attributes' => array('class' => t('node-readmore-link')),
              'html'=>TRUE
              )
     );
?>
```

You can read more [here](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=138)

Comment: This also hides the "read more" link on my homepage which I do not want... any chance, I can only hide the "read more" link on my gallery page?

Comment: please check my edit above, I replaced it with the lines you proposed but the read more links still show up: http://quaaoutlodge.com/gallery